# How to use a text macro in processor's include-directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need to constantly change the `#include` header file name (there are a lot of them), so I need something similar to this:

```
#define NUMBER 23

#include "file${NUMBER}.h"

int main()
{
    return run();
}
```

```
//Inside header files:
#pragma once
int run();
```

I know I can just replace the `${NUMBER}` with `23`, but I don't want to do it manually since I am going to use it in other lines of code, too. Also, I don't want to include all of them at runtime.

If this is not possible, what are other simple alternative ways to do this?

I am using Visual Studio.

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
#define s1 "file"
#define s2 "23"
#define concat(a,b) a##b
#define s3 concat(s1,s2)
#include s3
```

Comment: Sounds like a classic [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Please explain why you need (or 'think' you need) this functionality.  What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @G.M. I need to debug the program (look in assembly files, memory, etc...) and i think this will make it cleaner and if i include all the header files (which is more than 100) it will probably make me confused (I'm beginner c++ programmer)

Comment: Perhaps instead of having `file1.h`, `file2.h`, `file3.h`, and so on, you could change your layout so you have `dir_1/file.h`, `dir_2/file.h`, `dir_3/file.h`, and so on.  Then when compiling you could pass a flag like `-Idir_23` and that would allow the compiler to resolve only the desired `file.h`

Comment: You'll need to concat `file` and `23`, then turn that result into a string.

Comment: `I need to constantly change the #include header file name` Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not a “text macro”, it’s a macro definition. `${NUMBER}` is a syntax not defined in C++ standard for preprocessor directives, and you cannot use quotes directly.

If you read documentation for the `#include` directive, you will encounter something like this

> `#include X h-char-sequence Y new-line`
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `X` and `Y` delimiters

where `X` and `Y` are either `<` and `>` or quotes `"`. Text there is used verbatim.

The only way you can work around this is to use macro definition for the whole sequence, which sometimes is used by some libraries, e.g. by boost. This form of `#include` looks like

`#include pp-tokens new-line`

where `pp-tokens` is a legal sequence, processed like anywhere else in text. It should result in one of two forms above, otherwise the behaviour of `#include` directive is undefined - may result in error, but some implementations ignore empty sequences.

To create a text surrounded by quotes, a certain trick is required:

```
// #define NUMBER 23  // rather use -D compiler flag?

// ## operator is concatenation operator
// which joins verbatim parameter with surrounding 
// text to form something lexem-like 
#define FILE_NAME_NUM(f,N) f##N.h

// # is stringization operator which can be used only on a parameter
#define STRINGIFY_(s) #s
// this is required to process the paramater `macro` before # would
// surround it by quotes
#define STRINGIFY(macro) STRINGIFY_(macro)
#define NUMBERED_HEADER(f,N)  STRINGIFY(FILE_NAME_NUM(f,N))

// unfolds into #include "file23.h"
#include NUMBERED_HEADER(file,NUMBER)
```

It looks excessive, but it’s necessary because the preprocessor uses a very simple substitution algorithm. Function-like macro definitions aren’t functions.

What the preprocessor does:

1. Encountering `NUMBERED_HEADER(file,NUMBER)`, it would search for substitutes for file and `NUMBER`.
2. Finding `NUMBER`, it would replace it by 23, result: `NUMBERED_HEADER(file,23)`
3. It searches for `NUMBERED_HEADER` and replaces it with `STRINGIFY(FILE_NAME_NUM(file,23))` by substituting each parameter
4. It searches for `FILE_NAME_NUM` and replaces it with `file23.h` by substituting each parameter
5. `macro` in `STRINGIFY(macro)` is substituted by `file23.h`
6. `s` in `STRINGIFY(s)` substituted by `"file23.h"` due to `#` operator

For chevrons `<` and `>` it would be simpler, they can be used directly:

```
// still required for ##
#define FILE_NAME_NUM(f,N) f##N.h
#define NUMBERED_HEADER(f,N) <FILE_NAME_NUM(f,N)>
```

Comment: @EricPostpishil Just a curiosity: what's the point of replacing commonly used ' (U+0027 Apostrophe) with a character that cannot be typed ’ (U+2019 Right quotation mark). They are interchangeable